Connectivity problems with Windows 11
I am looking for solutions to connect my device (Xiaomi 12T- HYPEROS) to my computer (Hp - Win11).
The problem is that I have USB and wireless debugging activated, all my drivers updated, original USB cable, etc. I have done most of what the common solutions advise, it still doesn't connect. But if the PC detects it to load it and nothing else (even having activated file transfer)
Specifically, it is to use my device as a physical emulator with VS code and fluter, ran flutter doctor and everything is fine. I attach images, I would appreciate your support!!
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/1sw4o.jpg)
enter image description here
enter image description here
Finally, it is not a problem with the phone, it is with the computer, since I have tried with another Android phone and it still does not connect.

Please don't post terminal, output as screenshot. It is just text. Why do you use adb connect for an Android 12+ device which supports remote adb via adb pair? Have you checked Windows device manager if adb interface of your phone is correctly recognized?

@Robert Genius, adb pair was succesful, thanks so musch really, after various tutorials and possible solutions, only I had to search how to use adb pair and use it. Now I will can continue my flutter learning, thanks
